# How do I wait for a function in $.getScript() to finish before continuing?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns some data. The function needs to utilize another function from a different file, and to do this, I have a `.getScript()` running inside of it:

```
foo() {
    var bar;
    $.getScript("bar.js", function() {
          bar = FooBar.fooBar()
    });
    return bar;
}
```

The function `foo()` is used inside of another function, `bar()`. For `bar()` to properly continue, it needs the information that `foo()` returns. But it always returns null (when printed, it is `undefined` because I am not waiting for `.getScript()` to finish. If I put a `console.log(bar)` inside of the getScript, it prints after some time (a couple of seconds). How do I make my function `foo()` not return anything before getScript is done?

Comment: Call `.then` on the `getScript`

Comment: $.getScript("bar.js").then(function() {
              bar = FooBar.fooBar()
        });
        return bar;
    }
is not working for me (same occurence)

Comment: You need to `return bar` *inside* the `.then`, and also return the getScript call

Comment: @CertainPerformance Could you leave an answer? I think it would be clearer

Comment: Please read the linked canonical.